# Add GITHUB_TOKEN to Allow specified actors to bypass required pull requests or alternate solution

Tags: github, github-actions

Looking to confirm this is correct way to deal with the problem and if someone has a better idea.

I have the master branch set with protection, so you have PR into it and have signed commits.

I want to automate semver and current use:

```
      - name: Automated Version Bump
        id: version-bump
        uses: 'phips28/gh-action-bump-version@master'
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        with:
          skip-commit:  'true'
          skip-tag: 'true'
```

The have it working at present by removing my protection to the branch.

Looks like the solution is to add `Allow specified actors to bypass` genereate a PAT and use that for the token instead of the GITHUB_TOKEN.

I cant get GITHUB_TOKEN to be excepted in the field manually,

So

first question: Is it possible to GITHUB_TOKEN to the bypass list (Maybe its a variable syntax or something!)

second question: if i need to switch, if this the good solution, to create a new account go though least priv etc?

Comment: `Allow specified actors to bypass` is only available for repos owned by an enterprise organisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this via:

- creating a service account user that has read-write access to repo
- create a pat for that service account
- add the service account to the `bypass protection rules` in the branch
- create a repo secret that contains the PAT token
- update the line 'GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}' with the new secret

Comment: how to create a service account user that has read-write access to the repo?